# Clip to the complement of a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, transparency, path-clipping

I am attempting to make a tikz figure like the `Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students` in the tikz manual, but one which can be shown (without modification) on different background colors (I'm actually exporting to an SVG on a webpage that I'd like to work with "dark mode").

In the tikz tutorial, it is suggested to set the background color of the axis labels to white so that the axis doesn't show through the labels. However, if you do this on a different color background, the labels show up in white boxes (exactly like you asked for...).

[image]

Alternatively, if the figure could be clipped to the complement of the axis label's bounding rectangles, then the background color would show through without issue.

My question: is it possible to clip to the complement of the union of several node's bounding boxes? And then, can the content of those nodes be drawn on the "unclipped" figure?

Followup question: if so, could it be done for axis labels in pgfplots?

Comment: It depends on what you want to be blocked and what you want to not be blocked. In any case, look up the `even odd rule` for clip..

Answer (score 1):

Clipping the complement of a node:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {test};
  \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
    \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2)% outside border
      (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);% clipped area
    \fill[blue] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to do this in the other order? I.e., draw the big blue box and then clip it to a node?

Comment: No, the clip and the thing clipped have to be together.  You could achieve the same effect using \fill, but that will overwrite everything.